Nuxt testing: detect child component events
I am trying to test a nuxt page with vitest.
It has a child component toolbar which emits an event "on-click". When this event is triggered, the page calls a method "onClick". My test should verify this method is well called when the event happens:
Page:
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <MyButton @on-click="onClick" data-unit="btn" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const onClick = () => {
  console.log('on click');
};
</script>

Component:
<template>
  <button @click="onClick">CLICK ME</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const emits = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'on-click'): void;
}>();

const onClick = () => {
  emits('on-click');
};
</script>

describe('Test click', () => {
      let btn: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof wrapper.find>>;
      beforeAll(() => {
        btn = wrapper.findComponent('[data-unit="btn"]');
      });
      it('Should find the btn', async () => {
        expect(btn).toBeTruthy();
      });

      describe('Should listen the event', () => {
        it('Should listen to the btn events', async () => {
          const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'onClick');
          // wrapper.vm.onFilter({ ... });
          await btn.vm.$emit('on-click', { ... });
          expect(btn.emitted()['on-click']).toBeTruthy(); // Ok

          expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // NOK
          spy.mockRestore();
        });
      });
    });

If I call myself the method "onFilter" (commented line), the test passes. I suppose this is due to an event detection issue ?
Or can the "onFilter" method being called after I looked if the spy has been called ?
I guess it is a common purpose so I am looking forward to master this test case ... Thanks for your help
Here an example of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rar9hp?file=pages%2Findex.spec.ts

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unknown how these components are related

Yes you right: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-rar9hp?file=pages%2Findex.spec.ts

You probably need await nextTick() after a click. And you can't mock or spy on vm.onFilter (onClick) when it's called inside the component because you use composition api. Proceed from this and assert the side effects that it causes. In this case it's console.log() call but in real case it's likely something more meaningful. For future questions, please, provide relevant components as text in the body of the question, it needs to be understandable if external link becomes unavailable
